# The third node of the nats-streaming cluster does not rise in docker swarm

Tags: docker, docker-compose, docker-swarm, nats.io, nats-streaming-server

My project uses nats-streaming cluster. I want to raise it on three servers using docker swarm, but only 2 are successfully raised.
[(docker service ls output)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JcagG.png)
A non-working node outputs the following log:
[here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0u98E.png)

docker-stack.yml:

```
version: "3.8"

networks:
    network:
      driver: overlay
      attachable: true

services:

    nats-streaming-1:
      logging:
          options:
            max-size: "100m" 
      command:
        - "-sc"
        - "/etc/stan.conf"
        - "--cluster"
        - "nats://0.0.0.0:6222"
        - "--cluster_id"
        - $NATS_CLUSTER_NAME
        - "--clustered"
        - "--cluster_bootstrap"
        - "--cluster_log_path"
        - /data/log
        - "--cluster_node_id"
        - nats-streaming-1
        - "--cluster_raft_logging"
        - "--debug"
        - "--dir"
        - /data/msg
        - "--http_port"
        - "8222"
        - "--port"
        - "4222"
        - "--store"
        - file
        - "--stan_debug"
        - "--hb_interval"
        - $NATS_HB_INTERVAL
        - "--hb_fail_count"
        - "$NATS_HB_FAIL_COUNT"
        - "--hb_timeout"
        - "$NATS_HB_TIMEOUT"
        - "-mc"
        - "$NATS_STAN_MAX_CHNS"
        - "-mm"
        - "$NATS_STAN_MAX_MSGS"
        - "-mb"
        - "$NATS_MAX_BYTES"
      image: "nats-streaming:0.25.5"
      networks:
          network:
      ports:
        - "$NATS_PORT1:4222"
        - "$NATS_HTTP_PORT1:8222"
      volumes:
        - "nats-streaming-1:/data"
        - "./stan.conf:/etc/stan.conf"
      deploy:
        placement:
            max_replicas_per_node: 1
            constraints: [node.hostname == alex-swarm-3a]
    nats-streaming-2:
      logging:
          options:
            max-size: "100m" 
      command:
        - "-sc"
        - "/etc/stan.conf"
        - "--cluster"
        - "nats://0.0.0.0:6222"
        - "--cluster_id"
        - $NATS_CLUSTER_NAME
        - "--clustered"
        - "--cluster_log_path"
        - /data/log
        - "--cluster_node_id"
        - nats-streaming-2
        - "--cluster_raft_logging"
        - "--debug"
        - "--dir"
        - /data/msg
        - "--http_port"
        - "8222"
        - "--port"
        - "4222"
        - "--store"
        - file
        - "--stan_debug"
        - "--routes"
        - "nats://nats-streaming-1:6222"
        - "--hb_interval"
        - $NATS_HB_INTERVAL
        - "--hb_fail_count"
        - "$NATS_HB_FAIL_COUNT"
        - "--hb_timeout"
        - "$NATS_HB_TIMEOUT"
        - "-mc"
        - "$NATS_STAN_MAX_CHNS"
        - "-mm"
        - "$NATS_STAN_MAX_MSGS"
        - "-mb"
        - "$NATS_MAX_BYTES"
      image: "nats-streaming:0.25.5"
      ports:
        - "$NATS_PORT2:4222"
        - "$NATS_HTTP_PORT2:8222"
      volumes:
        - "nats-streaming-2:/data"
        - "/home/master/stan.conf:/etc/stan.conf"
      networks:
          network:
      deploy:
        placement:
          max_replicas_per_node: 1
          constraints: [node.hostname == alex-swarm-3b]
    nats-streaming-3:
      logging:
          options:
            max-size: "100m" 
      command:
        - "-sc"
        - "/etc/stan.conf"
        - "--cluster"
        - "nats://0.0.0.0:6222"
        - "--cluster_id"
        - $NATS_CLUSTER_NAME
        - "--clustered"
        - "--cluster_log_path"
        - /data/log
        - "--cluster_node_id"
        - nats-streaming-3
        - "--cluster_raft_logging"
        - "--debug"
        - "--dir"
        - /data/msg
        - "--http_port"
        - "8222"
        - "--port"
        - "4222"
        - "--store"
        - file
        - "--stan_debug"
        - "--routes"
        - "nats://nats-streaming-1:6222"
        - "--hb_interval"
        - $NATS_HB_INTERVAL
        - "--hb_fail_count"
        - "$NATS_HB_FAIL_COUNT"
        - "--hb_timeout"
        - "$NATS_HB_TIMEOUT"
        - "-mc"
        - "$NATS_STAN_MAX_CHNS"
        - "-mm"
        - "$NATS_STAN_MAX_MSGS"
        - "-mb"
        - "$NATS_MAX_BYTES"
      image: "nats-streaming:0.25.5"
      networks:
        - network
      ports:
        - "$NATS_PORT3:4222"
        - "$NATS_HTTP_PORT3:8222"
      volumes:
        - "nats-streaming-3:/data"
        - "/home/master/stan.conf:/etc/stan.conf"
      deploy:
        placement:
            max_replicas_per_node: 1
            constraints: [node.hostname == alex-swarm-3c]

volumes:
  nats-streaming-1:
  nats-streaming-2:
  nats-streaming-3:
```

The documentation says the following: "This is because the server recovered the streaming state (as pointed by -dir and located in the mounted volume), but did not recover the RAFT specific state that is by default stored in a directory named after your cluster id, relative to the current directory starting the executable. In the context of a container, this data will be lost after the container is stopped."
I assigned volume to the data folder and assigned --cluster_log_path to '/data/log', but it didn't help

Comment: use `configs:` to distribute `stan.conf` perhaps.

Answer (score 0):

Do know that NATS Streaming is end-of-life. A persistence layer is now available in NATS, called JetStream: https://docs.nats.io/nats-concepts/jetstream. Here is a webinar that discusses the transition: https://youtu.be/yKI9YmLx_8A and here is a migration example: https://natsbyexample.com/examples/operations/stan2js/cli

Comment: Thanks for the advice, but due to some circumstances we cannot migrate to nats-jetstream now